# Upgrading database version of an already built database

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have a database stored in my `assets` folder that I built using SQLite Manager. Now, when I add new records to any table of the database, I have to uninstall and reinstall the app. What would I have to do to upgrade the database in the right way without uninstalling the app?

**Note:**

- My `onCreate()` and `onUpgrade()` are empty because as I mentioned, the database is already built.
- I call `super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);` in my helper constructor, but changing the version would not do anything because `onUpgrade()` is empty.

Comment: Your SQLite Manager can generate the `CREATE TABLE`(s) and all the `INSERT INTO`s you need to populate the db. You might copy these command strings in your `onCreate` and `executeSQL` them in sequence.

Comment: `would not do anything because onUpgrade() is empty`. Then why don't you put something in `onUpgrade`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow upgrading, you must implement `onUpgrade` and do whatever is necessary to convert the old version to the new version.

If you have the new database file in the `assets` folder, you must replace the old file.
This is not possible with `SQLiteOpenHelper` because it has an active transaction while `onUpgrade` is called, but when you are not actually using the automatic creation/versioning mechanism, there is not reason to use `SQLiteOpenHelper` in the first place.

Comment: So, what would I have to use instead of `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Comment: You are not using any code in `SQLiteOpenHelper`, so there is not anything to replace it with. Just use `SQLiteDatabase` directly.